# Columns position on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a simple layout on bootstrap but I can't find a solution that doesn't involve javascript.

I need the template to be like this on medium / large desktops: http://jsfiddle.net/Xx3G4/1/

And it must stay like this on small devices: http://jsfiddle.net/Xx3G4/

If I wasn't clear enough, I need the block "p1":

```
<div class="teemo-block">p1</div>
```

to be right after the block "stuff" on medium / larges and after the news on small / x-small.

PS:

- Do not forget to re size the jsfiddle to see it on the correct viewport;
- The solution of this problem using javascript is pretty easy, the problem is finding one without the use of it.

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reposting and translating the answer I got on Portuguese SO (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9508/posicao-dos-blocos-em-bootstrap/9721#9721)

I have removed the classes `col-push` and `col-pull` and replaced them to `pull-left` and `pull-right`, also from bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 pull-right">
    <div class="teemo-block">
        p1
    </div>
</div>
```

Since, by default, all the 'cols' on bootstrap has float left, if you want to change that you must change it manually, that's why the news block got the `pull-left` and the other blocks got the `pull-right`, forcing them to stay on the desired position.

#### Check the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/hsCw9/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *twitter bootstrap* and if you don't have problem creating 2 "p1" blocks, one before and the other after the block "stuff", then there is one solution with the bootstrap class name. Bootstrap has a class called hidden-phone(renamed as hidden-xs in version 3), which hides the element with this class names in phones. [Check here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

The other solution would be to create 2 blocks as said above, use media queries to display one block and hide the other block. But this is not a pretty good solution, just in case if you don't find any other way without involving javascript

Comment: Technically, your answer is correct, but I want to avoid doubling the data.